# Looking for example logic to pull a DOM value into a Custom Script Adobe DTM data element

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-analytics

Actual Question:

Does anyone have any basic example logic of how to pull the value of a DOM element in to a custom script data element?

Background:

I'm trying to build some custom data elements in Adobe Dynamic Tag Management (DTM). I want to capture specific sections of my breadcrumb in to elements - e.g. Given breadcrumb trail Home >> Category 1 >> Category 4 >> Page 1, I would want X = Category 1, Y = Category 4, Z = Page 1

Unfortunately, the anchors in the breadcrumbs do not use consistent identifiers, so I need conditional logic in order to select them. Example: When I'm on the Category 1 landing page, the category's element has ID "Current" but otherwise it has the id "L1Link" - therefore I would want the following logic:

```
if(#L1Link exists)
   X = #L1Link
else
   X = #Current
```

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to select a DOM element in my Custom Function. I don't think _satellite.$data is what I want (I don't want data, I just want the text of the hyperlink). I tried using cssQuery, but I don't really have a callback to pass anything back to (and contrary to the documentation, it seems to get very upset if I don't have a callback).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to **Rules** > **Data Elements** and create a **Data Element** with the following:

**Name**: category_1

**Type**: Custom Script

Then click on "Open Editor" and add the following:

```
var x = document.getElementById('L1Link')||document.getElementById('Current');
if (x) return x.innerText||x.textContent;
else return '';
```

This will first look for #L1Link and failing that, will look for #Current. If it is found, it will return the link's text.

Based on your post, set **Remember this value for** as "Pageview"

**Save Changes**

Next, navigate to

**Rules** > **Page Load Rules**

If you don't already have a general page load rule setup that is set to pop on every page load, create one and name it something like "every page".

In the **Conditions** > **Criteria** choose **Data**:Custom from the dropdown and then click **Add Criteria**

Then add the following in the **Custom** textarea:

```
return _satellite.getVar('category_1')||true;
```

This condition will explicitly invoke the data element to ensure that it gets invoked, because DTM is moody and sometimes may not evaluate data elements. It falls back to `true` to ensure the condition always returns true, so that the condition will not cause the rule to fail to execute.

Then in the **Adobe Analytics** section of the rule, choose whatever `eVar` and/or `prop` you want to set (e.g. `prop1`) and set as `%category_1%`

**Save Rule**

You will want to repeat this process for each item you are looking to make a data element to pop an Adobe Analytics variable for, though you only need one rule, and one condition for all of them. The condition code would be:

```
_satellite.getVar('category_1');
_satellite.getVar('category_2');
//etc..
return true;
```

**NOTE:** DTM has some caveats of order of execution vs. load/timing of things. This is in part due to the nature of async loading but there is also a [mislabeling of order of execution in the documention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373076/has-anyone-used-on-page-s-contextdata-variables-successfully-with-dynamic-tag/22387416#22387416) (see my **Issue #2**) that Adobe has acknowledged. Basically, you may need to play with the **Trigger rule at** setting in the page load rule vs. what you set the "**Load Adobe Analytics page code at**" dropdown to in the Adobe Analytics Tool General config section and hope for the best. I setup a test page to verify all this in my post and pretty much anything I chose in either one worked, but then my test page had virtually nothing on it except the DTM page code and a link.

Comment: Ah hah! Okay, I see where this is going. Thanks much @crayon - and the extra notes about order of execution are super appreciated as well. That explains some other weirdness I was encountering.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting this post, always your explanations are very clear @crayon. By the way, you know how call data elements into script on Thirth party tags (HTML non sequential)? I'm trying to do and honestly, I miss.

When use a Java script non sequential I can take Data element, but my intention is pass Data Element value into image pixel, like:

```
<img src="//t.qservz.com/tr.aspx?campaign=169779d3852b32ce8b1a1724dbf5217d&type=ppl&retmode=4&orderid=[[orderid]]&totalprice=[[totalprice]]&level=**ValueDataElement**&redirect_url=[[URL]]" border="0" width="1" height="1"><img style="border: 0;" width="1" height="1" src="https://tags.qservz.com/pixel?id=1901&type=img" />
```

If you can help me, I'm grateful,

Julià.